# auth0 quickstart menu collapses but does not open

Tags: auth0

I just downloaded the auth0 quickstart vanilla JS single page application. The menu that you get when you resize the app, does not work.

instead, you get a error that says the collapse.js has a object error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this should save some time to other folks who are using auth0.

The problem is here, in the second line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.0.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason, jquery-3.5.0 has some problems with the dropdown menu working. The following worked for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am using 3.4.1 jQuery (second line again, above). That got the menu working.